# Aligning a checkbox and text in two different columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a display where there are 3 checkboxes. When one of these checkboxes is triggered, a message or input field should appear. I got that part working, but the checkbox and the message are not aligned as shown in the image below

[image: unaligned text]

As you can see the "Ondertiteling" checkbox is not aligned with the text "Ondertitel enabled".

This is my code (with the toggling of the message ommitted for the question's sake)

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox label {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                      <span>Aanvraag #1</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-remove pull-right icon-clickable"></i>
                  </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label> <input type="checkbox">Ondertitels</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label> <input type="checkbox">Vertaling</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox">Voice-overs</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div>Ondertitel enabled</div>
                        <div>Vertaling enabled</div>
                        <div class="text-danger">Voor voice-overs kan geen automatische prijsindicatie gegeven worden.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

How can I align the text to be on the same height as the checkbox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide your css on the class checkbox especialy

Comment: @RémyTeats it's the checkbox class from bootstrap (3.3.7). Added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask to *change* your markup to *fix* the formatting so that bootstrap will handle it for us. Change the markup into *rows* such as this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Vertaling</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="checkbox">Vertaling enabled</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

See demo below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
          <span>Aanvraag #1</span>
          <i class="fa fa-remove pull-right icon-clickable"></i>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox">Ondertitels</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="checkbox">Ondertitel enabled</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox">Vertaling</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="checkbox">Vertaling enabled</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox">Voice-overs</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="checkbox text-danger">Voor voice-overs kan geen automatische prijsindicatie gegeven worden.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was saying not on PC so couldn't provide code

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution of your problem is to create three separate rows and one row spanning total 12 columns, for which you will use 3 for one checkbox and other for your notification or message. 
So each message and check box will be bundled together in container or row class. 
Will provide code shortly, if you don't understand what I am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

remove the 10px margin-top from your checkbox class or add it to the othediv. I think this is what cause your offset. :)

Comment: I (kind of) have to leave the checkbox class as is, due to it being a bootstrap css class, otherwise every time I update bootstrap I will have to remember to change the checkbox class again

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you just need to add `margin-top: 10p`x and `margin-bottom: 10px` to your `div` inside the `col-lg-9`

Answer (score -1):

The answer you are probably searching is just changing the [line](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) or font height in your lg9 div

or using only one column, with checkbox and label having a constant width

Comment: I think this would fix the problem in this single case but it's more of a workaround instead of a proper fix. Thanks though!

Comment: yes the first is a workaround as it doesn't work with empy lines, but  the second works, if you put your lg3 and lg9 columns in it, beacause you want it to be lines before columns, so inline 'columns' divs inside block 'line' divs.